# PHP mysql_db_query being deprecated. Can't fix it

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-select-db

I'm getting the following error while connecting to my SQL database:

```
function mysql_query($query) {
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "p39438_***";
$dbpass = "password";
$dbname = "p31417_***";

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname); }
```

Using mysql_query gives me this error:

> Cannot redeclare mysql_query() in
>   /home/p39438/domains/***/public_html/_/includes/functies.php
>   on line 10

Comment: `mysql_select_db()` is not deprecated, only `mysql_selectdb()` is... As to the rest, you're not doing any error checking. Add error checking to see what the problem is. Also, your code is susceptible to SQL injection. http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Correct, mysql_db_query is however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `mysql_query()` not just `query()`. Also, don't put POST variables directly into a SQL query. That's a very bad idea.

Comment: using mysql_query gives me the following error:

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/p39438/domains/***/public_html/_/includes/dbUpdate.php on line 20

Comment: Do you have permissions to perform that sort of query? Has the connection definitely worked in the first place?

Comment: I am using the deprecated query function for a lot of websites in the past. I assume it will work.

Comment: It's deprecated. Don't use it.

Comment: I know, that's why i am trying to fix it. I don't get why i'm getting the errors for permission..?

Comment: The error message suggests you are trying to connect to the database as "apache" without using a password.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually EXECUTED your query:

```
$sql = "....";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is `mysql_query` not `query`. There's a theme with these mysql function names...